# C++ / W32 - Recording sound, Direct Show or WaveInOpen?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, audio, record

what to choose when thinking of WinXP, Vista, Win7 ++ :

- Record audio with Direct Show / Direct ... ?
- Go with classic WaveInOpen ( i've seen somewhere somebody saying that this is going to be oudated in W7/W8 - possible ? )

Ps. I need a callback functionality, to pass the buffer to the encoder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WaveIn is easy to use, there is plenty of example code on the net, and it gives you a callback in the way you need it.

DirectSound uses a circular buffer and can be a little cumbersome to set up, and most likely you'll need to take care of the circular buffer rather than "just filling a buffer". DirectSound, however, can give you tighter control of the audio, namely a bit better latency.

IMO, it's very unlikely that Microsoft will ever deprecate/remove the Wave API. They'd break thousands of applications. I actually don't think that MS has ever removed a core API from Windows.

So I'd go for the Wave API for simplicity.

Comment: Well said, luckily i have my WaveAPI wrapper Class ready. 

Thanks for info, i just needed to confirm that Wave API is in use.